"Custom" extensible arrows underneath text/symbols
First time asking a question here -- sorry in advance if the question is ill-posed.
It's kind of unconventional but I would like to be able to "accent" math symbols (or expressions) with vector-like arrows underneath them (pointing both right and left). Functionally, I'm essentially trying to modify \underrightarrow and \underleftarrow to have arrows more similar to the one you get from \vec. I think ideally, a way to use the arrow symbols that are available in esvect, but underset them instead of overset, would be perfectly acceptable.
What I have looked into:

I have actually tried to understand the source code of esvect to see if I could just modify it a bit to do the same thing but place arrows underneath text instead, but I just don't know enough about TeX at that level and I'm not sure I want to wade through pages and pages of scattered documentation to piece it together :/

It seems like this question/answer could potentially be modified to suit my needs if I could figure out how to get it to use a nicer-looking arrow (such as the one in \vec or some of those in esvect).

I don't have a lot of experience with mathtools or stackengine, but I've seen them used for solutions to some other somewhat similar questions about custom extensible arrows on here.

One point of confusion for me is exactly where the character used in \vec is specified -- I gather that it's font-dependent? But I don't understand the source/structure of TeX/LaTeX and the various packages well enough to determine precisely where the macro(?) \vec itself is actually defined -- and where it pulls the arrow symbol from whatever font is in use (I'm using all the usual AMS packages btw). I have looked somewhat carefully through this question/answer and there's some pretty useful info there but again I can't quite see how I would adapt it to underset the arrows instead of overset them. This question/answer also have some details about where the \vec character comes from, but they're using kpfonts and it isn't clear to me if that somehow changes the \mathchar thing?

It seems like there might just be a way to define a macro with TiKZ that would work but it would be nice if there were some solution that were even mildly more "standard" in some sense, I guess.


Any help is greatly appreciated!

Something like this? I just played with esvect macros.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\underrightarrow}[1]{\mathpalette{\underarrow@\vectfill@}{#1}}
\newcommand{\underleftarrow}[1]{\mathpalette{\underarrow@\rvectfill@}{#1}}
\newcommand{\underarrow@}[3]{%
  \vtop{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}
      #1#2\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\rvectfill@}[1]{\rtraitfill@\relbaredd\relbareda{\revfldr{#1}}{#1}}
\def\rtraitfill@#1#2#3#4{%
  $\m@th#4\mkern1mu#3\mkern-6mu#1\mkern-1.5mu%on met \relbaredd au d\'ebut
   \cleaders\hbox{$#4\mkern0mu#2\mkern0mu$}\hfill%remplit avec relbareda
   \mkern1mu$%
}
\def\revfldr#1{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\fldr$}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x+\underrightarrow{abcdef}$

$x+\underleftarrow{abcdef}$

$\scriptstyle x+\underrightarrow{abcdef}$

$\scriptstyle x+\underleftarrow{abcdef}$

\end{document}



oh man yes, thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I feel bad because it looks like I was almost there myself but got frustrated and gave up too soon haha :/ Edit: looking more closely, "almost" might have been a stretch lol. I just see ingredients that I kinda recognize from other answers/documentation I looked through. There is still quite a bit of technical low-level(?) TeX stuff I don't really understand in detail, though.

@max To be honest, I didn't really go into every detail: I just moved things around until the output was good enough.

Ok minor follow-up question: if I wanted to shift the arrows ever-so-slightly downward (by some fixed amount basically), would I just have to replace the \nointerlineskip with something like a \vskip or \glue or something else? I'm not sure what is best. Thanks again.

@max You can add \vspace{2pt} or what you deem best next to \nointerlineskip.

Ah ok wonderful. Thank you very much.
